# Call method with instance creator as receiver

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have class A, (NSDocument subclass) which stores my document data. Class A creates an instance of Class B, (NSView subclass) which manages the view. I want it so that every time the drawRect: method of Class B is called, it calls updateChangeCount: on Class A so that the user will know to save the document.

Comment: DrawRect shouldn't ever change state. Ever.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm _very_ new to this. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because -drawRect: can be called for a multitude of reasons (resizing, printing, screenshots, etc.) and should only handle drawing, nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted my comment I thought about it and realized that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely familiar with OSX projects and what exactly `drawRect:` does for `NSView`, so you may want to look into Richard J Ross III's comment.  But on the general question of one object calling a method on the object that instantiated it:

**ClassB.h**

```
@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>
@reqiured
- (void)someRequiredMethod;
@optional
- (void)someOptionalMethod;
@end

@interface ClassB <NSView>
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ClassBDelegate> delegate;
// Other stuff you need in your interface
@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
- (void)someClassBMethodThatNeedsToTriggerSomeClassAMethod {
    // stuff
    [self.delegate someRequiredMethod];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someOptionalMethod)]) {
        [self.delegate someOptionalMethod];
    }
    // stuff
}
```

Now, in ClassA, be sure you conform to this protocol:

```
#import ClassB.h

@interface ClassA <ClassBDelegate>
```

And implement the required method:

```
- (void)someRequiredMethod {
    // stuff
    NSLog(@"Hello world!");
    // stuff
}
```

And when you instantiate your `ClassB` object, be sure to set its delegate to yourself:

```
classB.delegate = self;
```

---

EDIT: Note, I put in an example of how `ClassB` can use optional methods as well as required methods.